# If-then-else matching issue

Tags: if-statement, sas

I am getting an error while running this code

> no matching if-then clause

```
if x=1 then do;
if diff>12 and (8<=p<=12 or 3<=p<5) then g=1;
else if (1<=p<=2) then g=2;
else g=3;
end;
```

pls help me understand my mistake?

Comment: @dwn That's equivalent to `if ( ) {  }` in c.  `do` begins a block that ends with `end` (otherwise the `if` just affects until the `;`).

Comment: @user1009587 There is nothing fundamentally wrong with the above statement, so you must have some other problem (perhaps a missing semicolon immediately before this, for example).

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code and ran the following:

```
data test;
x = 1;
diff = 14;
p=14;

if x=1 then do;
   if diff>12 and (8<=p<=12 or 3<=p<5) then g=1;
   else if (1<=p<=2) then g=2;
   else g=3;
end;
run;
```

What seems to be the problem?  Make sure x, diff and p are defined.

Comment: The problem is solved.. actually the code had some commented out portions having semicolon at the end. It worked fine after they were removed.. Thnx all..